# Understanding Days Sales Outstanding (DSO) Ratio

Tags: balance-sheet, income-statement, ratio

The definition of DSO is:

Days Sales Outstanding (DSO) = Accounts Receivable (AR)/Total Credit Sales * (# of days)

If you look at any finance website such as Investopedia, they will say the following:
https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/dso.asp

Days sales outstanding (DSO) is a measure of the **average number of days that it takes a company to collect payment** for a sale. DSO is often determined on a monthly, quarterly, or annual basis.

I do not understand how this measures  the **number of days** it takes to **collect payment** for sale. AR by definition is sales made on credit and dollars to be paid by the customer within the year--You may get the money, you may not.

Instead I think of DSO as the percentage of sales made on credit to customers.  This has nothing to do with the **number of days** it takes to collect.

I'd appreciate if anyone can help me understand this rather than just memorizing ratios.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AR is the amount of sales on credit *that have not been collected yet*. As new credit sales are made, AR goes up, and as people pay their bills, AR goes down.

As you look at a larger time period, the *total* sales goes up, but the A/R balance should stay roughly the same (it does not scale with time).

If you divide the average AR balance over some time period (e.g. a year) by the total amount of sales made on credit (not total sales), then you get a percentage. That is the average percentage of total credit sales that have not been collected.

Say in a year your average AR balance is 10% of your total credit sales. That tells you that *on average*, it took 36.5 (0.10 * 365) days to collect on your credit sales since your AR balance is about 10% of the overall sale balance. It's not an *exact* measure of the # of days it takes to collect since it could be skewed in either direction by larger sales but without detailed sales records it should be a rough average.

Comment: Thanks, but still not clear. Everything made sense until the last paragraph. AR is money we have not collected yet. So how can we make the statement it takes 36.5 days to collect on credit sales?

Comment: The assumption is that all sales are _eventually_ received, so if 10% of credit sales are outstanding on average in a year, then it takes _on average_ 36.5 days to collect them. The smaller that number, meaning the lower percentage of unreceived sales), the faster they are being collected. It's not an _exact_ measure but a rough estimate when looked at as an average. Using days is more intuitive to some analysts than just looking at the percentage.